# Need to calculate Percentage of product bought on every week based on week 1

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

Need to calculate Percentage of product bought on every week based on week 1.

week x % = Week X product bought / week 1 product bought

for example :
week 2 % = 70/100,
week 3 % = 50/100

but as soon as I introduce quarter other quarters are not calculating week 1 value and gives blank. Hence it goes

week 4 = 30/ blank.

DAX used =

```
 CALCULATE(
    DIVIDE(sum('Table'Product_bought),
    CALCULATE(sum('Table'Product_bought),  'Table'[weeks] =1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working now with the below Dax:

CALCULATE(
DIVIDE(sum('Table'Product_bought),
CALCULATE(sum('Table'Product_bought), ALL('Table'Quarter),  'Table'[weeks] =1))